# Rows with special characters not returned by query with like in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which contains rows with portuguese special characters in a column

```
table_a (id | description)
1  | "Value ã"
```

If a run a query than contains a like expression with special characters, the Postgres doesn't return those rows:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE UPPER(description) like UPPER('Value ã')
```

The query above doesn't return values, but there is a row with description 'Value ã'.

How to query rows that contains columns with special characters using like/ilike?

Comment: do you try `lower` instead of `upper` already?

Comment: Yes, I tried. No result too

Comment: Is the `description` value you're looking for `"Value ã"` or `Value ã`? I'm wondering where the double quotes are coming from: are they in the column value or are they an artifact of whatever you're using to look at the table?

Comment: Its working for me in 
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fSNPScLpxQcF2EHj9nhpfp/0.
minor issues are,  
table names are not matching in table structure and query,
double quotes being part of the actual cell value

Comment: Did you try `SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE UPPER(description) like UPPER('%Value ã%')`?

Comment: The problem is the LATIN1 encoding of my database. The postgres using that encoding doesm't convert a lower char to upper when it's a special character. I tried to upper the 'ã' char, but the upper() function returns the same char. The problem didn't occur with UTF8 encoding.